# Centering Text within a Silverlight Shape using a Canvas

Tags: canvas, windows-phone-7, centering

I have a canvas control which I'm housing a shape and some text in.

```
<Canvas x:Name="myCanv">
  <Rectangle x:Name="myRect" Stroke="Gray" Fill="Blue" StrokeThickness="3" Width="675" Height="350"/>
  <TextBlock x:Name="myText"/>
</Canvas>
```

In my code behind i'll be changing the text as events occur and I thought it'd be neat to place the text in the center of "myRect".

I found a great blog post on [how to center text in a canvas control in WPF app using MultiBinding Converters](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2010/01/04/centering-text-within-a-wpf-shape-using-a-canvas.aspx).  After reading it, I tried it out for WP7 only to be met with **pain!**

Unfortunately, it seems as though Silverlight 4 (of which WP7 Silverlight is a subset) doesn't have MultiBinding Converters.  I then found [a blog which has code for MbC in SL4](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/05/silverlight-multibinding-solution-for-silverlight-4/), but i can't open the project in VS2010 Express.

Has anyone either
A) Centered text via a value converter
or
B) found a better way to center the text without using a value converter

...? :)

Comment: WP7 is actually SL3 with a few extras not SL4.

Comment: Is the rectangle the only shape you are interested in?

Comment: Good call on the WP7 and SL3.  Thanks for clearing that up for me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just put the textbox outside the canvas in the visual tree but absolutely position it to the same size and location. You could then set the horizontal and vertical alignment on the textblock so that the text appears as if centered in the canvas.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a `Border` instead, that way you can simple set the Horizontal and Vertical Alignment properties of the TextBlock to Center.

```
<Border BorderBrush="Gray" Background="Blue" BorderThickness="3" Width="675" Height="350">
    <TextBlock Text="Hello" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Border>
```

Comment: There are other objects in my canvas object. I didn't add them in here to keep the example simple and also they have fixed positions. Sorry about that.